# Extracting data from CSV file using regular expression

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file like the following:

```
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004052,edf_eaf@gmail.com,edf,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004054,ghi_eaf@gmail.com,ghi,eaf
```

I would like to extract only the rows which have a second field that starts with the string `abc_`.

```
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '$2 ~ /^abc_/' file.csv
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

This uses `awk` with a comma as the field delimiter.  It tests whether the second field (`$2`) starts with the text `abc_`.  This is done with the regular expression `^abc_`.   If the test succeeds, the current line is printed.

---

If your input file is not a "simple CSV" file, but a CSV file that potentially has quoted fields containing embedded commas and newlines, then you need to use a CSV parser.  For example, you may want to use `csvgrep` from the [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) toolkit:

```
$ csvgrep -H -c 2 -r '^abc_' file.csv
a,b,c,d
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

This uses `csvgrep` to extract all records whose second column starts with the string `abc_`.  The first line of output is a header line that `csvgrep` creates for you since your input file doesn't contain one.  If you don't want this, remove it with by passing the result through `sed 1d`:

```
$ csvgrep -H -c 2 -r '^abc_' file.csv | sed 1d
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

See also `csvgrep --help`.

Answer (score 1):

Again assuming that this does not need parsing to avoid embedded `,`s in the first field then you could `sed` it too

```
sed -nE "/[^,]+,abc/p" file

1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

Do `-n`ot print every line but test with `E`xtended regex looking for a sequence that does not include any `,` with `[^,]+` and is followed by `,abc`. Then only `p`rint if you have a match

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
d=re.compile(r'abc')
l=open('filename','r')
for m in l:
    k=m.split(",")
    if re.search(d,k[1]):
        print m.strip()
```

output

```
1004051,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
1004053,abc_eaf@gmail.com,abc,eaf
```

Comment: let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: I did not vote it down, but "copy-paste this code" answers, without any explanation, are typically disliked on the site network.